# Different URLs but same images

Tags: python, urllib

My problem is this. The code snippet below, when executed, outputs three images. But they are all three the same image. So the code is overwriting all three images when a new URL is requested, instead of three specific images. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
import praw
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import random
urls = ['https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png' , 
'https://blog.uniquez.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1-%D9%85%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%B9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B9%D9%8A2.png' , 
'https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/08/Facebook-Collection-Video-Ads.png']
words = ['fewfewfwe' , 'fesfewfewf' , 'efefwefwefew']
for url in urls:
    for word in words:
        path ="image" + word + ".jpg"
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url , path)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Because that's how you programmed it. Write the first image into word1, word2, word3. Write the second image into word1, word2, word3. Write the third image into word1, word2, word3. Result: the third image three times. The first two images overwritten.

Comment: I edited the post, and made it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

```html
i = 0
for url in urls:
     path ="image" + words[i] + ".jpg"
     urllib.request.urlretrieve(url , path)
     i+=1
```

You have an inner loop inside the loop, so it compute 9 times. Actually you to compute it within a simple loop.

Comment: That gives an index out of range error. I'm working on a working full code snippet using your suggestion, but I have to go.

Comment: I change the order of i += 1 in the block, putting it in the bottom. Sorry, I make a small mistake

Answer (score 0):

What your current code does is save the first image to the file `imagefewfewfwe.jpg`, then the first image to `imagefesfewfewf.jpg` then to `imageefefwefwefew.jpg`, then overwrites all those files with the second image, then again with the third.

The pythonic way to save each image to a different file name, with url1 paired with word1, url2 with word2 etc., is to use the builtin `zip`, like so:

```
for word, url in zip(words, urls):
    path ="image" + word + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url , path)
```

Comment: If they are actually doing it this way, using a dict would be a ton nicer.

Comment: @Peter I agree that a `dict` would be an improvement, however a `dict` implies some kind of mapping - I think a list of tuples would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE NOTE THIS WAS TECHNICALLY ANSWERED BY The Blank. All this is is a full code snippet.

```
import praw
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import random
urls = [
    'https://blog.uniquez.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/%D9%85%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1-%D9%85%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%82%D8%B9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B9%D9%8A2.png',
    'https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png',
    'https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/08/Facebook-Collection-Video-Ads.png']
words = ['one' , 'two' , 'three']
i = 0
for url in urls:
     path ="image" + words[i] + ".jpg"
     urllib.request.urlretrieve(url , path)
     i+=1
```